# Apache Tomcat examples directory vulnerabilities

Tags: tomcat

I am facing Apache Tomcat examples directory vulnerabilities in one of the scenario,
what I use the pattern '..;' in url relaive path as below:
https://website.com/..;/manager/html as it's a servlet based application,
The issue occurs when I use '..;' or any pattern preceded by '..;'
https://website.com/..;..=../manager/html
I can resolve it by settings of listings parameter in <CATALINA_HOME>\conf\web.xml'.
Other than this resolution, how can we eliminate semicolon OR the patter '..;' in the URL.

Comment: which exact version of tomcat? And does this appear in Tomcat's stock code or is that in your own application? Proper handling of parameters typically falls into the hands of the application developer and you can't "eliminate" them from the URL, as that's what your client sends: You'll have to handle them properly.

Comment: Hi @OlafKock, Thank you , before reaching the request to the corresponding servlet file, due to the relative url pattern '..;' it could access the default directories in tomcat eben the listings is FALSE.
Below xml might be helpful to answer.
<web-app version="2.5" ...>
<servlet>

<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>


+<init-param>


-<init-param>

<param-name>listings</param-name>

<param-value>false</param-value>

</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

</web-app>

Comment: ...if you edit this into your question, you can even use formatting, and it will become readable... Also: Please mention the _exact version_ of tomcat that you're using (make sure it's not an ancient one please - otherwise check if it's long been fixed). Note that in case this is a security-relevant issue on the latest release of a supported version, it'd be nice to _not_ disclose it publicly, but directly to the developers.

Comment: Hi @OlafKock,  tomcat version is apache-tomcat-6.0.37, I will provide details by editing the question, but here I could not understand the pattern of '..;' ,  If the url contains this pattern then only it can access the admin manager.html file https://website.com/..;..=../manager/html, for suppose if it is 'https://website.com/.;..=../manager/html' (the pattern is '.;'), it can not be able to access manager/html directory.

Comment: Hi, can we restrict apache tomcat ui access for admin manager/html folder iff the url has https://localhost:8080/manager/html, in my case the other issue is the folder manager/html can be accessible from https://webaddress.com/..;/manager/html other than local host. Please suggest.

Comment: See my answer - that's what you need to do

Comment: Hi @OlafKock, please expecting one clarification from the overall concept, as a first attempt I am suggesting to upgrade the current version(6.0.37) to 6.0.53, after doing this, can't we accessible the manager/html OR other internal example directories other than localhost in the URL. Am I correct?

Comment: See my answer: "You might want to **try if** ...". I won't install discontinued software to try that for you, and it's only a short term fix, if upgrading to a current version requires more effort. Tomcat upgrades are typically quite smooth though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a version that was released in 2013 of a branch (6.0.x) that has reached its [end of life in 2016](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html). Since then, lots of security issues have been fixed.

The only sensible recommendation is to upgrade to a version that is still being maintained (eg Tomcat 9), and never again let yourself get so horribly behind the times again, especially on server side software.

You might want to try if 6.0.53 fixes this particular issue, but it is not a long term solution, just a quick way to try fixing *this particular issue that you're aware of* before you finally do a major version upgrade, to fix *all of the issues that you're not aware of* yet: